# I can block the option to paste in ui: inputSecret?

Tags: ui

I would like to know if you can block the option to paste in a component, ui: inputSecret

```
    <ui:inputSecret value="" aura:id="input1" class="field row-of-icons" maxlength="8" keyup="{!c.onKeyUp}"
    updateOn="keyup" label="Contraseña" />
```

I can not copy in the components but I can paste from other sides

Comment: You generally [should not do this](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/131106/39615) without good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ui:inputSecret` is deprecated and will stop working in the near future](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_aura_ui_deprecate.htm&type=5&release=230). Use `<input type="password">`. In the interim, if you really want to do this, put a wrapper around the element and catch onpaste from there:

```
<div onpaste="{!c.block}">
    <ui:inputSecret label="Demo" />
</div>
```

---

```
block: function(component, event, helper) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Unless you have a **very** good reason (and many would argue there is no good reason), you [should not block pasting passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/131106/39615). This encourages using weak passwords and may actually help compromise security controls.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take that recommendation into account